# Poker equity calculation algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, playing-cards

I writing some specific poker equity calculator. Basically, equity calculator tells how much one hand is more profitable than other. I have written such calculator and it works, works fast, but there is a one not optimal place where a lot of time is spent and it definitely can be optimized. I am asking you about the advice how to optimize it.

Below is the simplified structure of poker equity calculator. For sample purpose, I have made it for the game when both Players hands contain one from 52 cards, 4 cards are on board(turn), one(river) board card left. Let say that player who's sum of the board and hand card is higher - wins.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static const int card_count = 52;

// Checks that board contains the card. A lot of time spent here. Need to be optimized.
bool Contains(const std::vector<int>& board, int card)
{
    for (int boardCard : board) 
    {
        if (boardCard == card)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Fake function that evaluates hand strength. This is just for example real evaluator is different. So no need to optimize this.
size_t GetHandStrength(const std::vector<int>& board, int card, int b)
{
    size_t stren = 0;

    for (int boardCard : board)
    {
        stren += boardCard;
    }

    return stren + card + b;
}

// Returns equity for the board 
float GetEquity(const std::vector<int>& board)
{
    float equity = 0;

    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < card_count; c1++) // Player1 card
    {
        if (Contains(board, c1))
        {
            continue;
        }

        for (int c2 = 0; c2 < card_count; c2++)  // Player2 card 
        {
            if (c1 == c2 || Contains(board, c2))
            {
                continue;
            }

            size_t usedBoards = 0; // number of boards are possible for this players and board cards
            float currentEquity = 0;

            for (int b = 0; b < card_count; b++) // Iterating river board cards
            {
                if (Contains(board, b))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (b == c1 || b == c2) // Check that there are no conflict with players cards
                {
                    continue;
                }

                size_t p1stren = GetHandStrength(board, c1, b);
                size_t p2stren = GetHandStrength(board, c2, b);

                if (p1stren > p2stren)
                {
                    currentEquity += 1.0;
                }
                else if (p1stren < p2stren)
                {
                    currentEquity -= 1.0;
                }

                usedBoards++;
            }

            currentEquity /= usedBoards;
            equity += currentEquity;
        }
    }

    return equity;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    std::vector<int> board = { 0, 1, 2, 21 }; // Some turn random board (4 cards)
    float equity = GetEquity(board);;
    cout << "equity: " << equity <<  endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When iterating over the hand and board cards I need to check that board doesn't already contains the card, so I need to iterate over the board cards again and again. This is done by the bool `Contains(const std::vector<int>& board, int card)` also checks like if `(b == c1 || b == c2)` What can you suggest to optimize this part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're doing an *O(N³)* operation, with a linear search, a big performance boost will happen if we can eliminate that search.

There are two similar ways to go about it; both replace the search with an indexed lookup.

- Change the type of `board` from a vector that holds the cards to a vector (or `array`) of `card_count` slots that holds a count of how many of that card is in the board (using a count for future expansion to multiple decks).
- In `GetEquity`, fill a vector or array of `card_count` elements with counts for the cards in `board`, then just check that container for a nonzero to see if the card is contained in the board.  This has the additional advantage of being able to add `c1` and `c2`, so the inner loop checks only need to check one condition (rather than 2 or 3) to see if a card is available.

Here's an updated `GetEquity` using ideas from option 2:

```
float GetEquity(const std::vector<int>& board)
{
    std::vector<int> counts(card_count);
    for (auto b: board)
        ++counts[b];

    float equity = 0;

    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < card_count; c1++) // Player1 card
    {
        if (counts[c1])
        {
            continue;
        }
        ++counts[c1];

        for (int c2 = 0; c2 < card_count; c2++)  // Player2 card 
        {
            if (counts[c2])
            {
                continue;
            }
            ++counts[c2];

            size_t usedBoards = 0; // number of boards are possible for this players and board cards
            float currentEquity = 0;

            for (int b = 0; b < card_count; b++) // Iterating river board cards
            {
                if (counts[b])
                {
                    continue;
                }

                size_t p1stren = GetHandStrength(board, c1, b);
                size_t p2stren = GetHandStrength(board, c2, b);

                if (p1stren > p2stren)
                {
                    currentEquity += 1.0;
                }
                else if (p1stren < p2stren)
                {
                    currentEquity -= 1.0;
                }

                usedBoards++;
            }

            currentEquity /= usedBoards;
            equity += currentEquity;

            --counts[c2];
        }
        --counts[c1];
    }

    return equity;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two player equity on the river can be calculated with the single loop through possible player's holdings.

Here is a pseudo-code of a general idea.

```
foreach (board in all_possible_boards) {
    all_cards = all cards except for those on board
    ordered_hands = sort(all_cards, compare hands by hand strength on a given board)

    win_probabilities = dictionary Hand -> Value;

    for (i=0; i< len(ordered_hands); i++) {
       win_probabilities[ordered_hands[i]] = i / (len(ordered_hands) -1); 
    }
    sum up the results
}
```

This code assumes that all hands have different hand strength, but it can be relatively easily adjusted to handle ties. Handling more complex games like two-card poker or even four-card poker is a bit trickier but also possible. Extending it for multi-player scenarios is something even more tricky.